# How to install these specific packages to `amazonlinux2`

Tags: linux, rpm, deb, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

Well, basically I was using a ubuntu distribution of docker image and had to run the following command to install the exact packages as below into it:

```bash
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true \
    && apt-get -q update \
    && apt-get -q dist-upgrade -y \
    && apt-get -yq --no-install-recommends install \
    libssl-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libsasl2-dev \
    openssl \
    libldap2-dev \
    curl \
    ldap-utils \
    && apt-get autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

The problem is that I might need to move from this unix distribution to use an `amazonlinux2` docker image, then facing the issue of installing the exact same packages into the new image.

I am a really newbie when talking about difference between RPM and DEB packages, I actually don't know how different each OS is from each other and I am not able to know what package in `amazonlinux2` would be related to the ones listed above.

Do anybody know what packages I need in this new docker image? I mean, what is the equivalent of `libsasl2-dev` in the RPM repo for amazonlinux2 etc...

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

To find what's the equivalent of `libssl-dev` on amazonlinux2, you can google :

```
"libssl-dev" redhat equivalent
```

The very first entry of search results gives you `openssl-devel`, so you can run

```
yum install openssl-devel
```